# Возможно ли реализовать следующую функциональность в wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, шаблонизаторы

Нужна помощь в реализации создания динамичных страниц на вордпрессе:

- Имеется меню с категориями, каждая категория отличается своим контентом.
- Кликнув на одну из категорий мы переходим в каталог подкатегорий.
- А внутри каталога подкатегорий находятся сами товары.
- Кликая на товар открывается страничка с самим товаром и переключение между предыдущим и последующим товаром.

Для наглядности есть видео где все показано: [Ссылка на видео о данной проблеме](https://youtu.be/709TMOaxZa8)

При создании шаблонов я создавал их **отдельно**, но я не знаю как динамически всё это дело написать, чтобы не приходилось каждый раз для каждой категории и подкатегории создавать отдельный файл. Вот таким вот образом я обращаюсь к файлу своему, и всё это происходит статически: http://prntscr.com/jp8vqy но задача заключается в том чтобы сделать его динамическим и не зависящим от шаблона.

И вообще возможно ли такое сделать на Wordpress или лучше какую нибудь другую технологию использовать? Что можете посоветовать для этого?

Comment: новый уровень вопросов, с видео :D нормально)) Я не силен в WP, но там есть возможность создавать статические страницы, вот если на них все закрутить - то это возможно самый простой способ, либо искать плагины.

Comment: Вопрос можно было сформулировать "Можно ли создать онлайн магазин на WP", ответ - WooComerce. И в целом, вопрос "Возможно ли реализовать" - некорректен, возможно все, вопрос в затратах

Answer (score 1):

> Вот таким вот образом я обращаюсь к файлу своему, и всё это происходит
>   статически: http://prntscr.com/jp8vqy но задача заключается в том
>   чтобы сделать его динамическим и не зависящим от шаблона.

Я, честно говоря, не очень понимаю почему Вы не используете [стандартный цикл](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/) для вывода товаров, но если на то есть причина, то получить текущую рубрику, находясь на странице рубрики, можно с помощью

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$slug = $queried_object->slug; //здесь должно быть collection-mod-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Изложеннная задача является типичной для WordPress: категории, подкатегории, товары в них. Для вывода категорий в WordPress существуют общие шаблоны. Не надо городить отдельный шаблон под каждую категорию, а, как справедливо отметил Денис, использовать стандартный цикл WordPress.

Для решения вашей задачи целесообразно использовать плагин WooCommerce - самый распространённый в мире магазин электронной торговли. Создать дочерню тему WordPress, в неё скопировать шаблон вывода категории WooCommerce, отредактировать его таким образом, чтобы в категориях выводились только подкатегории, а не товары, кроме категории нижнего уровня, которая будет выводить товары. Вывод товаров реализовать с прокруткой типа слайдера, как у вас в видео.

Ничего уникального в реализации этой задачи на WordPress + WooCommerce я не вижу.

Answer (score 0):

На WP можно практически все. Тем более с разделами и навигацией. Если Вы знаете как работать с движком через код, то это будет сложновато. На счет плагинов, не подскажу. Но думаю если Вы обратитесь к фрилансеру, с понятным ТЗ, то возможно Вам сделают то что Вы хотите. В вашем случае если я не ошибаюсь, можно сделать даже без плагинов (кроме) вывода товаров (типо подгружаем 10 товаров в скролл) либо просто показываем 10 рандом товаров этой же категории под основным.

Comment: То есть насчёт плагинов не подскажете? Я не могу найти нужный плагин.. Я то знаю то как решить эту задачу на других технологиях, на WP я новичок.. И мало в нём разбираюсь